# Need Program that will make the CPU run at 100%

Tags: c, cpu-usage

I need a program, that will make my CPU run at 100%.

Preferably in C, a tiny program, that will make the CPU run at 100%, and one, that is not "optimized" by the compiler, so it does nothing.

Suggestions?

Comment: If you are on *nix then the yes program should do just that for you

Comment: I need the program to heat the computer. It sounds strange, I know. The laptop in question is out on my balcony. I need to heat it during night time, so moisture doesn't kill it and it doesn't, well freeze.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int main(void) {
  volatile unsigned x=0, y=1;
  while (x++ || y++);
  return 0;
}
```

Or, if you have a multi-core processor -- *untested ... just like the one above :)*

```
int main(void) {
#pragma omp parallel
  {
    volatile unsigned x=0, y=1;
    while (x++ || y++);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

What about this one:

```
int main() { for (;;); }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a good, old-fashioned fork bomb.

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
  while(1)
    fork();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: he said "run at 100%", not "die in a heap"!

Comment: I took a look at his avatar and made an educated guess :)

Comment: anyhow, for a real fork bomb try this in Bash - `:(){ :|:& };:`

Comment: I don't want to forkbomb that computer, I just need it to run at 100%

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste this in a file named `source.c`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv) {
    while(1);
}
```

Compile `source.c`: `gcc source.c -o myprogram`

Run it: `./myprogram`

Comment: You don't need the include ... or main arguments for that matter

Answer (score 0):

The answers suggesting an empty loop shall only bring dual core CPU to 50%, quad-core to 25% etc.

So if that is an issue one can use something like

```
void main(void)
{
    omp_set_dynamic(0);
    // In most implemetations omp_get_num_procs() return #cores 
    omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_num_procs());
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(;;) {}
}
```

Comment: `void main` RAAAAGRRRRGGGHHHH!

Comment: If something calls an `extern "C"` function that never returns, how can it tell that this function returns the wrong thing?

Comment: -1 for `void main` UB. Also only a broken OMP implementation would parallelize a loop with no side effects.

Comment: Care to provide the relevant paragraph from OpenMP spec?

Comment: Link instructions missing, it seems to need a library - gives link errors.

Answer (score 0):

Native Windows solution for multithreaded systems. Compiles on Visual C++ (or Visual Studio) without any library.

```
/* Use 100% CPU on multithreaded Windows systems */

#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 4

DWORD WINAPI mythread(__in LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    printf("Thread inside %d \n", GetCurrentThreadId());
    volatile unsigned x = 0, y = 1;
    while (x++ || y++);
    return 0;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HANDLE handles[NUM_THREADS];
    DWORD mythreadid[NUM_THREADS];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        handles[i] = CreateThread(0, 0, mythread, 0, 0, &mythreadid[i]);
        printf("Thread after %d \n", mythreadid[i]);
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```